# Loading images from Asset library to a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I'm using **ELCImagePicker** https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController in order to pick my images from the phone's library. ELC has two options to return, the first is the UIImage itself (which I don't want as it crashes due to memory when picking more than 5 images). The second is the asset location of the image, this is good for the memory, although my problem is while showing the images on the collection view.

So I have this piece of code that works fine and shows the images, but when I scroll up and down through the collection view, it lags a bit. I assume it's because every time it wants to load a cell it has to go through a block and its asynchronous. I'm trying to find a way to remove the lag and make it scroll smoothly.

*Any help would be much appreciated. :)*

```
 ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

 [library assetForURL:_chosenImages[indexPath.row] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.thumbnail];
  // I believe the problem is here..
    [myCell.imageView setImage:image];
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"An error occurred while loading image: %@", error.description);
}];
```

Comment: In my case when I was dealing with a situation like this. I had used ALAssets instead of AssetURL in an array. Change your data source to contain assets instead of AssetURL.

Comment: How would this be any different?

Comment: In the sense that you will not have to to fire an asynchronous call to fetch asset and then it's image every time to try to display a cell in the collection view. The [asset thumbnail] is fast enough to not create lag on your main thread.

Comment: I get something that looks like this: {
    UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = ALAssetTypePhoto;
    UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1A255C21-88AB-4F62-83FA-D23547825C58&ext=JPG";
}  It's my first time using Assets so how can I actually get the Asset from this? It's placed in an NSDictionary.

Comment: see my answer below. once you have modified your datasource to hold assets, then in the cell display method, remove the asynchronous call to fetch asset. just get the asset using index path and then thumbnail. Then display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `- (void)selectedAssets:(NSArray *)assets` method in `ELCImagePickerController.m` you will be able to see this line

```
ALAsset *asset = elcasset.asset;
```

after this line, there is a dictionary created which then addd to `returnArray`. Skip this dictionary creation part. Add the asset to the returnArray directly. change the for method to look like this:

```
for(ELCAsset *elcasset in assets) {
    ALAsset *asset = elcasset.asset;
    [returnArray addObject:asset];  
}
```

Have fun.

*****EDIT*****
Also please create a singleton to maintain the life of the `AssetLibrary` in `ELCAlbumPickerController`.

Comment: I tried this solution, but instead of returning just the Asset I returned the Asset within the dictionary (essentially the same thing) although I encountered another problem, if I scroll, the images now disappear and this is logged: invalid attempt to access <ALAssetPrivate: 0x1685f440> past the lifetime of its owning ALAssetsLibrary .. Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: it means the AssetLibrary `self.library` used for the retrieving Assets has deallocated, in `ELCAlbumPickerController`. check for it ..

Comment: So again the solution will be, creating a singleton for the AssetLibrary?

Comment: its there in just one place `[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];` if you are not able to keep hold of he asset library, you can always create a Singleton for the `AssetLibrary`. And I guess you will have to because I believe you will be using the assets later to get `fullimages`.

Comment: Ok great, I'll do that. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it works perfectly! :) Although you might want to edit the answer to include that a singleton must be created in order to maintain the AssetLibrary. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `ALAssetsLibrary` doesn't guarantee that the result block is called on the main thread. You should do the expensive stuff (generating the `UIImage`) on a background thread, and any UI work should be done on the main thread. So you need to fix that first:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.thumbnail];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [myCell.imageView setImage:image];
    });
});
```

Second of all, when you finally get to `myCell`, this cell is no longer guaranteed to have the same content. This is because cells are reused during scrolling. So you need to get the correct cell.

One common approach is to use the `indexPath`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.thumbnail];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        MyUICollectionViewCellSubclass *correctCell = (MyUICollectionViewCellSubclass *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [correctCell.imageView setImage:image];
    });
});
```

However, this will only work if the index paths are guaranteed not to change which may or may not be the case depending on your use case. For example, if the user can insert or delete items, you'll need to take a different (but similar) approach.

Finally, make sure to `nil` out `imageView`'s `image` when reusing a cell (so you don't show old images as the cells scroll in.)

---

Also, it's been a while since I used the assets library, but I think you shouldn't use `imageWithCGImage:` but rather `imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:`. I believe the method you're currently using will look blurry on Retina devices, and might get the orientation wrong.

Comment: So I've done the first part where I put it in the main thread, but I can't initialise the cell inside the block as cellForItemAtIndexPath should return that cell. By doing the first part alone, it doesn't seem to change anything and it still lags. Also, I do get the cell correctly, as I said, it returns the correct image at that specific cell, but takes some time to load (which is the issue) :)

Comment: I'm going to reply the same way I replied to the comments above as it is the same problem. 

I get something that looks like this: { UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = ALAssetTypePhoto; UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1A255C21-88AB-4F62-83FA-D23547825C58&ext=JP‌​G"; } It's my first time using Assets so how can I actually get the Asset from this? It's placed in an NSDictionary.